# Django how to reuse views functionality common to all views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django template, let's call it index.html which is divided in 3 parts (header, content and footer). In the header section I have a search bar that includes a drop-down menu which allows the user to select an option from it and search things based on the selected option. I want that header section to be include in all my future views/templates and still display the drop-down menu with all the options.

This is what I currently have in my view file

```
def index(request):
    return render(
                    request,
                    'home.html',
                    {'categories': get_all_categories()}
                )


def cart(request):
    return render(request, 'cart.html', {'categories': get_all_categories()})


def help(request):
    return render(request, 'help.html', {'categories': get_all_categories()})


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {'categories': get_all_categories()})


def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'categories': get_all_categories()})


def search(request):
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'categories': get_all_categories()})


def get_all_categories():
    return Category.objects.all()
```

This is what I have cart.html
    {% extends "index.html" %}

```
{% block content %}

<div>
<h1> My Cart </h1>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is what contact.html has
    {% extends "index.html" %}

```
{% block content %} 

<div>
<h1> Contact </h1>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is what home.html contains
    {% extends "index.html" %}

```
{% block content %}

<div>
<h1> Home </h1>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This works right now but I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this so that I don't have to repeat the same code in all of the views.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) to include that variable in every template you render.

For example, write a context processor like the following (in `context_processors.py`, say):

```
def category_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'categories': get_all_categories(),
    }
```

And include it in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'myapp.context_processors.category_context_processor',
        ],
    },
}
```

Now the variable `categories` is available in every template you render (using the `render` call or a `RequestContext`, anyway), regardless of the context you actually pass from the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a template tag.

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        poll_extras.py
    views.py
```

In yours poll_extras.py file

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_categories(request, arg1, arg2, ...):
    return {
        'categories': get_all_categories(),
    }
```

Or you can use a inclusion_tag with its own template (staying the same in all views):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('categories_block_template.html')
def get_categories(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(field1=arg1, ...)
    ...
```

And finally, in the template you need to load the templatetag and use it:

```
{% load poll_extras %}
```

You can see more about templatetags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

Comment: And in my opinion [Django Classy Tags](https://django-classy-tags.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a plus.